# Issue with importing Maven project in STS from Spring Guides

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Spec: `jdk1.8`, `Spring Tool Suit Editor-3.8.2`, `Maven 3.3.3`, `Windows10 O/s`

Downloaded the **ZIP** from **url** : https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input

*Error on MAVEN as follows*

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gs-validating-form-input 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] The POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.4.3.RELEASE:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Question** : *Why is this Error shown ?*

Comment: there are two module initial and complete, which produce this error info.

Comment: seems like an issue with your local m2 repo. In order to double check it , could you locate the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf directory for `1.4.3.RELEASE` inside your local m2 repo , and post what files it contains. If it doesnt contain a valid .jar , then delete it and force mvn -install to fix the local m2 repo

Answer (score 1):

The project is OK, i downloaded, imported as **Maven project** in eclipse and i run it as a **Spring boot app**.

I am using M2Eclipse 1.7

Try cleaning your project.

Try to Right click -> Maven -> Update project.

Try right click -> Run us -> Spring Boot app.

Comment: Try to Right click -> Maven -> Update project.  --- Did This...also ...but same error ..... I have other Maven POM's that work well with out problems.

Comment: How do you import the project in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps (in Eclipse or in Spring Tool Suite) after you download and unzip this project [Validating Form Input](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input):

1. In your Eclipse or STS IDE **`File → Import...`**. In the Import window choose **`Maven → Existing Maven Projects`**.
2. Select the root directory as path to your unzipped project, e.g., **`C:\gs-validating-form-input\complete`**. Click `OK` and `Finish`.
   *Note: select **`complete`** folder if you want to see the final result or **`initial`** if you want to follow this guide step-by-step*.
3. When your project successfully imported expand **`src/main/java/hello`** package in Project Explorer or Navigator. Right click on the **`Application.java`** class **`Run as →`** then either `Java Application` or `Spring Boot App` (or just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then press <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>b</kbd> correspondingly).
4. That's all. Go to your browser, and type `http://localhost:8080/` in the address bar.

Comment: fix this add the following dependency ...did this with version as per the Site Instructions ...but Same ERROR ...

Comment: Seems like STS is the problem,...works with Eclipse NEON .....This may be helpful for somebody..

Comment: I just followed these steps in STS, it works perfectly as well as in Eclipse. Make sure you have valid STS [downloaded here](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all).

Answer (score 0):

I download this project and right click `complete` *open command line* then **mvn install**, everything is ok.

> The POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.4.3.RELEASE:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available

it seemd you cant download this jar from [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.4.3.RELEASE) so Check your setting.xml and repository path. 
And if you use eclipse Check your windows > preferences > maven > setting.

Comment: Maven Installation works with other projects...Also Maven setting is good in STS -Eclipse ...

Answer (score 0):

Unzip recently imported folder from https://start.spring.io/
Use Import option pointing at unzipped folder, you could see project got selected. 
This way you can import Maven project in to STS IDE